# Array passing to functions differences

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, pointers

I want to ask if there is difference between this two array passing method:

```
unsigned char array[100];

function(array);

Where: 

library.cpp
uint8_t LibraryClass::function(unsigned char array[]) { }

library.h
uint8_t function(unsigned char array[]);
```

And this:

```
unsigned char array[100];

function(array);

Where: 

library.cpp
uint8_t LibraryClass::function(const unsigned char* array) { }

library.h
uint8_t function(const unsigned char* array);
```

My questions is:

- There is difference between this to methods?

Additional question:

- My MCU need to do additional operation in method 1 instead of method 2?
- There is additional const in method 2, why is used? It is safety to use const when using pointers?

Comment: Generally, C files have a .c extension and C++ files often have a .cpp extension. Are you sure you are using C (the languages are not the same)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `unsigned char array[]` is just syntactic sugar for `unsigned char *array` in a function declaration. They're literally identical.
2. The `const` means that `function` guarantees not to modify the contents of `array`. The first example makes no such guarantee to the caller.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there are 3 different kinds of `const` for pointer arguments: when the pointer itself is const, the pointed to data is const, or both are const. The guarantees made by the function signature are different in all 3 cases.

Comment: There is only one `const`, it just might apply to different things. This case is the one described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in c/c++ **unsigned char array[]** is **unsigned char* array** which consists of contiguous memory.

Whenever an array is passed to a function it is treated as **pointer(*)** denoting the base address.

Mentioning const- **(const unsigned char* array)** denotes its value will not change.